# Login issue on RestKit for iPhone

Tags: authentication, restful-authentication, restkit

I'm having hard time understanding this problem:
I'm using Restkit for iPhone sdk 5.0 and I'm doing the login in a class Session

```
NSString* url=[[[RKClient sharedClient]baseURL]stringByAppendingString:@"/users/sign_in"] ;

    RKRequest *request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] delegate:delegato];

    request.queue = [RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue;
    request.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTP;

    request.username = utente.email;
    request.password = utente.password;
    [request send];
```

delegato is my "master" Class where I called the login method.

Then I implemented the request:didLoadRespons where a wrote these lines:

```
if ([response isSuccessful])

    RKLogDebug(@"Login effettuato con successo %d", response.statusCode );
```

This always returns 200 as status code (always tried with correct e-mail and password), but when I get the recent questions from myWebServer/recent.json, I have an empty response (I also tried with an object loader which did the same) as it does when I'm not connected.

The log system printed me this string:

**2011-12-06 11:58:20.480 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:362 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL mysite/recent.json.
2011-12-06 11:58:20.484 APP[4364:fb03] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared GET URLRequest ''.** HTTP Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
2011-12-06 11:58:20.486 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:272 Sent request  from queue . Loading count = 2 of 5
2011-12-06 11:58:20.487 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:443 Received response for request , removing from queue. (Now loading 1 of 5)
2011-12-06 11:58:20.622 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 406
2011-12-06 11:58:20.623 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    Age = 0;
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 06 Dec 2011 10:58:20 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/0.7.67";
    Via = "1.1 varnish";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.006494";
    "X-Ua-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    "X-Varnish" = 1786715586;
}
2011-12-06 11:58:20.623 APP[4364:fb03] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body:
**2011-12-06 11:58:20.624 APP[4364:fb03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:562 Status Code: 406**
2011-12-06 11:58:20.624 App[4364:fb03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:563 Body:
2011-12-06 11:58:20.625 APP[4364:fb03] Si è verificato un errore con il seguente codice 406
2011-12-06 11:58:20.625 APP[4364:fb03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:443 Received response for request , removing from queue. (Now loading 0 of 5)

What does this mean?

Thanks so much for the help.

the json is:

```
{
"_id":"4ede406d5040dc0001000009",
"answers_count":2,
"cache_slugs":[
{"_id":"4ede406d5040dc000100000a","slug":"faccio-prova-di-domanda"},
{"_id":"4ede41d8bf3a9e0001000008","slug":"faccio-prova-di-domanda"},
{"_id":"4ee61fd7f24ee9000100008b","slug":"faccio-prova-di-domanda"}],
"created_at":"2011-12-06T16:18:53+00:00",
"detail":"",
"followed_by_user_ids":["4eca5fa1166f360001000014","4eca5fa1166f360001000014","4dd43ff93c40760001000004"],
"slug":"faccio-prova-di-domanda",
"text":"faccio prova di domanda",
"topic_ids":[],
"updated_at":"2011-12-12T15:37:58+00:00",
"user_id":"4eca5fa1166f360001000014"}
```

And my mapping is like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* questMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Question class]];
    questMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes=YES;
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"_id" toAttribute:@"idDomanda"];
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"text" toAttribute:@"titoloDomanda"];
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"detail" toAttribute:@"dettaglioDomanda"];
    //[questMapping mapKeyPath:@"user_id" toRelationship:@"identificativo" withMapping:userMapping];

    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"dataCreazione"];
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"aggiornataAlle"];

    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"answers_count" toAttribute:@"numeroRisposte"];
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"topic_ids" toAttribute:@"topics"];
    [questMapping mapKeyPath:@"followed_by_user_ids" toAttribute:@"followers"];


    [objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:questMapping];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:questMapping forClass:[Question class]];
```

And my login cod is this:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:self.email];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:self.password];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client=[RKClient sharedClient];
    RKParams *params = [RKParams params];

    [params setValue:self.email forParam:@"username"];
    [params setValue:self.password forParam:@"password"];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] setAuthenticationType:RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTP];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/users/sign_in" params:params delegate:delegato];
```

Is this right?

Comment: Sorry guys, i was wrong doing the GET request, i had to post it.
But i can't make the login. What should i use: RKRequest or RKClient or RKObjectLoader?

Comment: If you want to benefit from the object mapping features that restkit offers you should use `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:`

Comment: Well the point is not only how to do it but is also doing it, since actually i can't do it! i do le login i check the respons is succesfull but when, with the objectloader, i try to loda /blabla.json it doesn't work and it gaves me error 404.
How can i fix this?

Comment: i need to see your code. If you get 404 then the URL is wrong.

Comment: Well apparently everything is fine but the login procedure! i do it fine with the objetManager post method but apparently the JSON that the server returns to me doesn't have a RootkeyPath so it tells me that he cant find a mapping for  ther key ' '. It seams i have to modify the JSON the server sends me!...right?

Comment: You can map the JSON even if it does not have the root key, please see my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409115/how-to-post-an-object-to-rails-using-restkit/8412991#8412991

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand, with this code [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:listMapping forKeyPath:@"list"]; you are actually defining a rootPath. How do i tell restKit not to map the response with a rootPath but just with the classMapping i give him?

Comment: the thing is tha i can't do the login but the response of didLoadResponse is actually succesfull but the response is the http code of the registration page of my site...

Comment: i don't follow the second part of your comment. Please, post the following: expected JSON request that is necessary for your backed to execute login procedure, the server response to that request, your RKMappings as defined in your code and the invocation of RKObjectLoader methods.

Comment: i see the updated question, but please add the code where you retrieve the data from your server (RKObjecLoader calls)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/5820/login-issue-on-restkit-for-iphone?tab=general

Comment: i can't join that chat. i used to use the object loader call but now i' using this! it's hard to understand which is the correct (standard) way to do it i'm switching from one to another without any success!

Comment: to clarify things a bit - what is the issue with your login exactly? You need to parse the server response or something? I'm not sure what you want to achieve. How does the authentification work? Do you need to be logged in in order to access the recent.json? If so, isn't it enough to supply the username&pw to RestKit when you are querying for recent.json?

Comment: 1) i'm loggin in with the above method and as response i get the html page that says "please register" => no good!
2)No i don't but it seems the login process is saccesfull while it doesn't (i check if [response isSuccessfull])
3)The authentication works as a normal HTTP one
4)Yes, i'm using that get as a login check

Comment: there are few issues in your code, firstly when you define serialization mapping you should use `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[questMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Question class]];` and try loading your objects using this call:     `RKObjectLoader *loader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath objectMapping:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Question class]] delegate:delegate];`

Comment: so the login worked properly, basically i had to wrap email and password in a dictionary and wrap it in a dictionary for the key user.
now i can retrive the recent.json and map it but i can't figure how to put the result in a tableview!

THANKS SO MUCH mja!!!!!

Comment: and what's the issue exactly? does it have something to do with restkit or you have troubles with TableView in general?

Comment: no no RestKit warks fine! it was just me, i used to do the request like this:
[[RKRequest sharedClient] requestWithResourcePath:@"/users/sign_in"]

RKParams *params = [RKParams params];
[params setValue:password forKey:@"password"];
[params setValue:username forKey:@"username"];

[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/users/sign_in" params:params delegate:self];
Which was wrong because i had to define the params like this:
RKParams *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[  NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.email,@"email",self.password,@"password", nil],@"user", nil];

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the mapping using `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mapping];` Further details are in the [documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) and look up the "Mapping without KVC" part

Comment: I did but it seems not working. If i do the same steps from a browser i works and the call /recent.json gave me all the recent questions.
Plus the response to that request continue giving me the 200 status code!

Comment: please post your json, mapping and the code you use to retrieve records.