# Rails RestKit POST request json's root class missing

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, xcode, restkit

I had this previous problem which I fixed, but I know the fix is def not done the right way. Can some one point me in the right direction for the right fix?

Basically I create a object with iOS sim via `RESTkit` `postObject`, and I got this message:

```
Processing PeopleController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-13 03:55:46) [POST]
  Parameters: {"name"=>"data"}

Person Create (0.4ms)   INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name")
VALUES('2012-01-13 11:55:46', '2012-01-13 11:55:46', NULL)
Completed in 27ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK
```

A nice gentlemen pointed out that my class inside my create function is only accepting a :person class which I overlooked.

```
def create
@person = Person.new(params[:person]) , thus looking for {"person" => {"name"=>"data"}}
```

I fixed this by doing

`@person =Person.new(name:=>params[:name])` since i am only sending `{"name"=>"data"}`
now it creates ok, and I can see the entry on my ios sim. But I know this is not the right way. The right way should be `{"person" => {"name"=>"data"}}` sent in to the original function. Plus I get an error could not find an object mapping for keyPath:". Any thoughts?

Here is my xcode:

```
@interface Data: NSObject{// imaginary over arching class
   Person * person;
   NSArray *dog;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person * person;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * dog;

@interface Data : NSObject {
Person *person;
NSArray *dogs;
}
@property (nonatomic ,retain) Person *person;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) NSArray *dogs;
@end

@interface Person : NSObject {

NSString *name;
NSNumber *personId;
NSDate   *updatedAt;
NSDate   *createdAt;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDate * createdAt;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDate * updatedAt;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSNumber  *personId;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *name;
@end

RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];

[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"personId"];

RKObjectMapping* dogMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Dog class]];
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"person_id" toAttribute:@"spersonId"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"dogId"]; 

RKObjectMapping *dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"dog" toAttribute:@"dogs"]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"person" toRelationship:@"person" withMapping:userMapping]; 
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:dataMapping]; 

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/people"       
objectMapping:dataMapping delegate:self]; 

RKObjectRouter * router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people/:personId"];
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people"          
forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

RKObjectMapping *personSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:
[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[personSerializationMapping attribute:@"name", nil];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider 
setSerializationMapping:personalSerializationMapping forClass: [Person class]];

Person *dave = [[Person alloc]init];
dave.name = @"Dave";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:dave delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: thnx @favo for editing my chicken scratch =]

Answer (score 2):

Take `Person` as an example:

```
RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];

[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"personId"];
```

To config `RestKit` to `POST` with a root path, replace:

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] 
         setSerializationMapping:personalSerializationMapping 
                        forClass:[Person class]];
```

with:

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider]
                 registerMapping:objectMapping 
                 withRootKeyPath:@"person"];
```

Now Rails will receive `{"person" => {"name"=>"data"}}` instead of `{"name"=>"data"}`.

For reference, here is the *magic* of `registerMapping`:

```
- (void)registerObjectMapping:(RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping withRootKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    // TODO: Should generate logs
    objectMapping.rootKeyPath = keyPath;
    [self setMapping:objectMapping forKeyPath:keyPath];
    RKObjectMapping* inverseMapping = [objectMapping inverseMapping];
    inverseMapping.rootKeyPath = keyPath;
    [self setSerializationMapping:inverseMapping forClass:objectMapping.objectClass];
}
```

it does both `setMapping` and `setSerializationMapping` with the clever `[objectMapping inverseMapping]` trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yea finally figured it out. The mapping was wrong. Instead of `addObjectMapping: dataMapping`, it should have been  `userMapping` with `keyPath` person which is `userMapping`. btw thnx @favo for editing my chicken scratch =] now it can `GET` and `POST` fine!

Comment: ITs actually still not working i forgot i hacked the source code in Rails for def create  to take in a name instead of a person but that broke the webside of the server... so it still doesn't work =/

Answer (score 0):

For completionist sake, the error about "could not find mapping for key path ''" seems to be a thing with Rails create action.

There's a good answer for this problem in this SO question: [how to post an object to Rails using RESTKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409115/how-to-post-an-object-to-rails-using-restkit)